# Groovy json parsing using JsonSlurper

Tags: java, json, parsing, elasticsearch, groovy

I am trying to parse following json i am getting from elastic-search api in groovy using jsonslurper . I need to create a list of _id out of this json. Tried multiple variation of code but no success

please suggest , any help appreciated.

```
{
  "took" : 2535,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 384,
    "successful" : 384,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "X",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "310165903526204",
        "_score" : null,
        "sort" : [
          "310165903526204"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "X",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "310165903698515",
        "_score" : null,
        "sort" : [
          "310165903698515"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "X",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        **"_id" : "310165903819494"**,
        "_score" : null,
        "sort" : [
          "310165903819494"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

PS:  I tried using multiple clients provided by elasticsearch to search ES and parse data but i am facing another issue with that, so had to switch to HTTP client and do manual parse . this is link for client issue [RestHighLevelClient with Elasticsearch client error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73248052/resthighlevelclient-with-elasticsearch-client-error)

Update:

```
{
  "took" : 19,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 370,
    "successful" : 370,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3961655114649",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "location" : {
            "lat" : 14.94046,
            "lon" : -23.48016
          },
          "place" : {
            "country" : "USA",
            "pois" : [
              {
                "externalIdentifier" : "3961655114649",
                "gdfFeatureCode" : "7376",
                "officialNames" : [
                  {
                    "name" : "ENG",
                    "language" : "ENG"
                  }
                ],
                "alternateNames" : [ ],
                "brandNames" : [ ],
                "streetsAndCities" : [
                  {
                    "city" : "California",
                    "cityLanguage" : "UND"
                  }
                ],
                "postalCode" : "",
                "postalCodeMain" : ""
              }
            ],
            "providers" : [
              {
                "UniqueId" : """{"mostSigBits": 6332787932357083, "leastSigBits": -6052983698683356}""",
                "code" : "ABC",
                "deliveryId" : "3959",
                "rawId" : """{"mostSigBits": 8772023489060096, "leastSigBits": -6327158443391381}""",
                "totalAttributes" : "1",
                "visibleAttributes" : "1"
              },
              {
                "UniqueId" : """{"mostSigBits": 6332787932357083, "leastSigBits": -6052983698683356}_1""",
                "rawId" : """{"mostSigBits": 8772023489060096, "leastSigBits": -6327158443391381}""",
                "totalAttributes" : "1",
                "visibleAttributes" : "1"
              }
            ],
            "attributes" : [ ],
            "isAddObservation" : false
          },
          "transactionCommitDate" : 0
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

With this updated Json, i want to pull mostSigBits and leastSigBits values in typeId under providers. but the catch is i want to pull only that typeID inside providers[] which is not having _1 or _2 or anything suffix with it.

i have tried to get that data by doing this but looking for some better approach

**json.hits.hits[0]._source.Place.provider[0].typeId**

Answer (score 0):

```
def _id = json.hits.hits.collect{ it._id }
_id.each{println it}
```

Comment: i have new update for this same question, can you suggest better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Basic Groovy's object navigation is here to help:

```
import groovy.json.*

String response = '''\
{
  "took" : 2535,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 384,
    "successful" : 384,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "X",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "310165903526204",
        "_score" : null,
        "sort" : [
          "310165903526204"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "X",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "310165903698515",
        "_score" : null,
        "sort" : [
          "310165903698515"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "X",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "310165903819494",
        "_score" : null,
        "sort" : [
          "310165903819494"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}'''

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText response

List ids = json.hits.hits*._id

assert ids.toString() == '[310165903526204, 310165903698515, 310165903819494]'
```

Comment: i have new update for this same question, can you suggest better way to do it.

Comment: the json of your update can't be parsed. Post the original one w/o formatting

Comment: added original json

Comment: `"""` is not allowed in json

Comment: there is no """ in my json i updated, i think you are confusing with the Json in your answer . @injecteer

Comment: no, it stands right in your text: `"UniqueId" : """{"mostSigBits": 6332787932357083, "leastSigBits": -6052983698683356}"""`. It seems like a stringified piece of json